# PreparedStatement.setTimestamp is not inserting Timestamp into DB

Tags: java, mysql, timestamp, prepared-statement

I am working on account management system. Goal is to set trial period into db. I am getting `Timestamp "2015-10-30 22:55:48"` from `jsonObject` into REST service and inserting into db using prepared statements. But each time I am getting `effected rows 0` and means update operation is not performed!

I have tried following piece of code including parsing and conversion:

```
JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
Object obj = parser.parse(requestBody); 
JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;

String accountExpiryStr = jsonObject.get("accountExpiry").toString();

SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
Date parsedDate = dateFormat.parse(accountExpiryStr);
Timestamp accountExpiry = new Timestamp(parsedDate.getTime()); // accountExpiry output is 2015-10-30 22:55:48.0

String requestQuery = "UPDATE table SET Account_Expiry = ?"
                + "WHERE Account_Id = ? "
                + "AND User_Id = ? ";
preparedStatement = con.prepareStatement(requestQuery);
preparedStatement.setTimestamp(1, accountExpiry);
preparedStatement.setInt(2, Integer.parseInt((String) jsonObject.get("selectedUserId")));
preparedStatement.setInt(3, Integer.parseInt((String) jsonObject.get("accountId")));

rowCount = preparedStatement.executeUpdate();

System.out.println("Effected Rows: " + rowCount);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Affected rows = 0` means that the where clause of the UPDATE did not match any record in your table. So you should first check if the where clause is correct.

Seems you have switched user id and account id...
Instead write:

```
preparedStatement.setInt(2, Integer.parseInt((String) jsonObject.get("accountId")));
preparedStatement.setInt(3, Integer.parseInt((String) jsonObject.get("selectedUserId")));
```

Comment: Thank you; I am trying figuring out problem from last hour finally I thought it is strange and posted it here :P